# Multiple export with dot notation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have this code:

#### Sidebar.jsx

```
class Sidebar extends Component {
    render() {
    return (
        <div className="sidebar">
          { this.props.children }
        </div>
    );
  }
}


class Item extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <b> { this.props.name } </b>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export { Sidebar, Item };
```

#### index.js

```
export {default as Header} from './Header';
export {default as Footer} from './Footer';
export {default as Sidebar, Item} from './Sidebar';
```

#### app.jsx

```
import { Sidebar } from '../components';
class App extends Component {
  render() {

    return (
      <div>
          <Header/>
          <Sidebar>
              <Sidebar.Item name='item1' />
              <Sidebar.Item name='item2' />
              <Sidebar.Item name='item3' />
          </Sidebar>
          <Footer/>
// ...
```

The error that I get is:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'Item' of undefined

How I can multiple export component in `index.js` and call from another file? I'm sure that Header and Footer work correctly because I have only one class in that file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
function Sidebar(props) {
    return (
        <div className="sidebar">
          { props.children }
        </div>
    );
}


function Item (props) {
    return (
        <div>
            <b> { this.props.name } </b>
        </div>
    );
}

Sidebar.Item = {Item}

export default Sidebar
```

Then you can use it like this

```
import Sidebar from './Sidebar.js'

...

return (
    <Sidebar>
        <Sidebar.Item />
    </Sidebar>
)
```

If you're using class based components, you can remove the curly braces

```
class Sidebar extends Component {
   render() {
       return (
           <div className="sidebar">
               {this.props.children}
           </div>
       );
   }
}


class SidebarItem extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <b> {props.name} </b>
            </div>
    );
}

Sidebar.Item = SidebarItem;

export default Sidebar;
```

I learned this practice from a coworker that saw it in semantic ui's table [here.](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/blob/master/src/collections/Table/Table.js)

Comment: I think is like https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#using-dot-notation-for-jsx-type. Thanks - EDIT: Just tried now but I got that error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Comment: I think not work because I need a React.Component not a function.

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect that possibility. Thanks!

Comment: @Galupuf How would you do this in Typescript?

Comment: I'm no sure, as I am not rehearsed in Typescript. You could, however, post another question to ask :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

`import { Item } from '../components';`

and then use it:

`<Item name='item1' />`

Comment: Also, Sidebar is not the default export from Sidebar.js

Comment: Doing like you say is a problem when I create other components like Menu and MenuItem.