# Multiple exports with dot notation in Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

#### Ref. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48996762/multiple-export-with-dot-notation).

I'm trying to do exactly the same, but with Typescript.

#### Problem

This line (just before the export statement):

```
Sidebar.Item = SidebarItem;
```

gives compile error: `Property 'Item' does not exist on type 'typeof Sidebar'`

#### Attempted solution 1

I've tried adding Item to my Sidebar class definition, like so:

```
class Sidebar extends Component<SidebarProps, SidebarState> {
    Item: SidebarItem;
    ...
}
```

But that results in this error: `Public property 'Item' of exported class has or is using private name 'SidebarItem'.`

#### Attempted solution 2

I've tried removing this line:

```
Sidebar.Item = SidebarItem;
```

And instead of adding Item to my class definition, I'm exporting both classes like so:

```
export default Sidebar;
export { SidebarItem as Item };
```

Which does compile, and I am able to import everything like so:

```
import * as Sidebar from '...';
```

But then I have to use them like so:

```
<Sidebar.default>
    <Sidebar.Item></Sidebar.Item>
    <Sidebar.Item></Sidebar.Item>
</Sidebar.default>
```

And I really want to get rid of that `.default` in `Sidebar`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first solution is almost correct, but you declare `Item` as a property on objects of the `Sidebar` class, rather than on the class itself. You can do the latter with a static property declaration. This should work:

```
export class SidebarItem ..
..
class Sidebar extends Component<SidebarProps, SidebarState> {
  static Item = SidebarItem;
..
export default Sidebar;
```

You won't need the line `Sidebar.Item = SidebarItem;` anymore, but you might need to move the `SidebarItem` class so it appears before `Sidebar`. The import will just be `import Sidebar from '...'`.

Answer (score 1):

This module is faulty by design.

It likely can be done with:

```
export class SidebarItem ...

export default class Sidebar extends Component<SidebarProps, SidebarState> {
    static Item = SidebarItem;
    ...
}
```

And there is no good reason why these two components should maintain a hierarchy like that.

It's conventional to have *CamelCased* components and use separate named exports if there's more than one export of equal value (which components are). Named exports are better for auto-import in IDEs:

```
export { Sidebar, SidebarItem };
```

`Item` cannot be tree-shaken from default export when needed. `Sidebar.Item` minifies less efficiently than `SidebarItem`.

Comment: Many thanks for your detailed answer! `there is no good reason why these two components should maintain a hierarchy like that` Are you saying that simply because of the class names? Please note that these class names aren't real (I just used the same class names as in the linked question). My actual case is very different, where neither component will ever be used without the other (`Item` will always be a child of `Sidebar`).

Comment: You're welcome. Any way, keep in mind that it's not conventional to use component class as a namespace for children (minification is the only real problem that comes to mind, but there could be others).